# Is it possible to put "on the one hand" between 'to' and the verb?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Most of the time the construct is used as follows:

> On the other hand, it is used to fertilize the soil.

Is it possible to, e.g., say:

> It is used to, on the other hand, fertilize the soil

I already tried to search in a corpus, but only found one instance where it was used. Linguee, while not being the best source, only showed one result, too. Searching via Google was successful, yet the quality of the sources is not always obvious. Could anybody help?

Comment: (It would be possible if you shifted the preposition **to** in front of **fertilize**.

Comment: It is used, on the one hand, to fertilise the soil, and, on the other, to flavour my mother's soups. Why repeat 'used' and 'hand'?

Answer (score 1):

In the middle of the infinitive is an awkward spot to put "on the other hand", which is why you're not finding many hits. I wouldn't say it's impossible (though there are certainly spots that you absolutely cannot put it, such as in the middle of a noun phrase). The meaning of your sentence would be understood regardless.

Usually, "on the other hand" shows up at the start or end of a sentence or after the subject.